# Need correct Xpath for country dropdown

Tags: selenium, xpath

Our application is using third party tool like Kendo UI so i am unable to find correct xpath but i tried most of xpaths but not working.[image]

County
                
                select

```
        <span class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="CountyID_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="CountyID_option_selected" style=""><span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default"><span unselectable="on" class="k-input"></span><span unselectable="on" class="k-select"><span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s">select</span></span></span><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CountyID must be a number." id="CountyID" name="CountyID" type="text" data-role="dropdownlist" style="display: none;"></span>
        <span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default"><span unselectable="on" class="k-input"></span><span unselectable="on" class="k-select"><span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s">select</span></span></span>
        <span unselectable="on" class="k-input"></span>
        <span unselectable="on" class="k-select"><span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s">select</span></span>
        <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s">select</span>
```

I'm receiving the below error.

> Error:
>   Element should have been "select" but was "span" Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host: 'NAV-L186', ip: '192.168.0.186', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_212' Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Comment: Share the HTML in plain text.

Comment: Can you share the xpaths that you have tried so far?

Comment: @AppuMistri This is my xpath //*[@id="form_CreateClient"]/div[1]/div[3]/span/span/span[2]/span

Comment: @AppuMistri after executing this error message is appearing Element should have been "select" but was "span"
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'NAV-L186', ip: '192.168.0.186', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_212'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Comment: That's because drop down is build using span tag not with select tag, you can't use select class from selenium for drop down which is built using span tag.

Comment: @zafarahmad as mentioned in abovecomment, you are trying to perform select action on a `<span>` tag, which is incorrect. Selenium can perform select action only on `<select>` tag. You might have to design a customized strategy to select from your dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this XPath = `.//[span[text()='select']`. But I would request you to paste the whole HTML in plain text so that it could be easy to deduce a dynamic XPATH.

Comment: XPath = .//[span[text()='select'] not working this xpath and l also add HTML code please review it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? xpath = "//span[@class='k-icon k-i-arrow-s']